# How to weight different categories by their item count

Tags: statistics

I want to weight my categories by the amount of items they have. More items in a category -> less weight.

e.g category A has 10 items
category B has 20 items
category C has 2 items

Category C should have the highest weight. Can someone point me in the right direction to achive this?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Exact problem:

There are 10,000 unique Items in a collection. Each item has a variable number of attributes from different categories and we need to rank them in a ranking system.

Score =  1 / (( Number of unique Items with that attribute * Attribute category normalized) / 10,000)

TotalScore = Sum of Attribute Scores

Now I need to normalize the categories to give more score to categories with less attributes

In my test colleciton there are 166 attributes in 22 categories (some category with 2 attributes some with 30)

expected results:
Item has attribute0 with 738 others and the categoryA has 17 attributes -> should give score 8.36

Item has attribute1 with 5391 others and the categoryB has 2 attributes -> should give score 9.72

Comment: Please share the exact problem, so that we have a better idea of what is required.

Comment: @MattiP. I updated the question